# On Mouseover show large Images without Distortion

Tags: jquery

On Mouseover show large Images without Distortion 
Also the images come from database using php so my question is that any simple method is there
in jquery css javascript etc which would be simplest
Thanks.

This is the code where images shows from the database

```
     <div>
   <table>
<tr>
  <td>
    ?php
    $query = "SELECT * from images";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<img src=\"http://localhost/images_path/{$fetch['image']}\" width=\"15%\"     height=\"135px\">"." &nbsp";
}
?>

</td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide some code to show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple css..

```
div.img img { height: 90px; width: 110px; }
div.img img:hover { height: auto; width: auto; }
```

Another method maybe

```
function mouseOver()
{
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
img1.src ="images/p2.jpg";
img1.width = "";
img1.height = "";
}
function mouseOut()
{
var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
img1.src ="images/p1.jpg";
img1.width = "90";
img1.height = "110";
}
```

Also have a look at this [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HmTrw/1081/)

Comment: What do u mean by structure disturbance??

Comment: second method is nice. but my images are pulled out from database so how i add this code to that.